# Setting download preferences in my basic setup method

Tags: python, selenium

I am defining the download preferences in the setup method so everytime I need to download a file I do not have to define it seprately it will automatically download. Is this the right way to do that? It is giving me the error:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options, executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
```

TypeError: **init**() got multiple values for keyword argument 'executable_path'

```
class BaseTestCase(object):


        def setUp(self): 
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
            options.add_argument("download.default_directory=os.getcwd()")
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options, executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
            #self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options)
            self.driver.maximize_window()
            self.driver.get("https://abcc.com")



        def tearDown(self):
            self.driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `"download.default_directory=os.getcwd()"` as one string, i.e. the function `os.getcwd()` is never executed. Change the line to

```
"download.default_directory={}".format(os.getcwd())
```

The correct [format](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver) for initiating the webdriver is:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am assuming it will set the download preferences for every test.